# Spark equivalent to Keras Tokenizer?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tokenize, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

So far, I pre-process text data using numpy and build-in fuctions (such as keras tokenizer class, tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/text/).

And there is were I got stuck:
Since I am trying to scale up my model and data set, I am experimenting with spark and spark nlp (https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/annotators#tokenizer)... however, I couldn´t yet find a similar working tokenizer. The fitted tokenizer must be later available to transform validation/new data.

My output should represent each token as an unique integer value (starting from 1), something like:

```
[ 10,... ,  64,  555]
[ 1,... , 264,   39]
[ 12,..., 1158, 1770]
```

Currently, I was able to use the Spark NLP-tokenizer to obtain tokenized words:

```
[okay,..., reason, still, not, get, background] 
[picture,..., expand, fill, whole, excited]                     
[not, worry,..., happy, well, depend, on, situation]
```

Does anyone have a solution which doesn´t require to copy the data out of the spark environment?

**UPDATE:**

I created two CSVs to clarify my current issue. The first file was created thru a pre-processing pipeline: 1. [cleaned_delim_text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15XE7Z42ooxqnfxA5Vu7aSSrAFcmc7npe/view?usp=sharing)

After that, the delimited words should be "translated" to integer values and the sequence should be padded with zeros to the same length: 2. [cleaned_tok_text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jCZPwDhmRAgKoHEDmljpCNpp8tbp-zQU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below combination -

**1. Use [tokenizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tokenizer) to convert the statements into words and then**

**2.use [word2vec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#word2vec) 
to compute distributed vector representation of those words**

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I might misconceive it, but W2V is an embedding method, right? I rather just want a "simple" word-to-integer translation as in my example.. not an vector representation. So I end up with a dict, similar to the keras tokenizer. Does this makes sense?

Comment: can you provide sample input and output?